# How to find the number of subarrays in an array with given sum?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My program should be as following:

```
Input : {1,2,3,2,1,8,-3},  sum = 5
```

Output should be 3 example combinations `({2,3}, {3,2}, {8,-3})` have sum
exactly equal to 5.

I tried to do it in JavaScript but I'm confused.

```js
function findSubarraySum(arr, sum) {
  var res = 0;
  var currentSum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    currentSum += arr[i];

    if (currentSum == sum)
      res++;
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(findSubarraySum([1, 2, 3, 4], 10));
```

Comment: You need to learn at least one algorithm for finding sub-sets of a given set.

Comment: Thanks you for your comment

Comment: Does your sub-arrays need to be contiguous or can you use indexes 0,1,and 3?

Comment: How would you do it with pen and paper?

Comment: What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: @FelixKling about how to do it.

Comment: @DougCoburn adjacent numbers only

Answer (score 0):

You first need a way to iterate over all the unique ways you can choose a start and and of your subarray boundaries (your slice definition).

In my code below, I use a combinations function to get all possible combinations of two indexes for the array supplied.  You could do something else, like a simple doubly nested for loop.

Next you need to take the slice of the array according to the slice definition and reduce the elements into a sum.  The Array.prototype.reduce function works well for that.

Finally, you want to include the subArray in the list of results only if the reduced sum matched the desired sum.

```js
// Input : {1,2,3,2,1,8,-3},  sum = 5

const { combinations, range } = (() => {
    const _combinations = function*(array, count, start, result) {
        if (count <= 0) {
            yield [...result]; // Yes, we want to return a copy
            return;
        }

        const nextCount = count - 1;
        const end = array.length - nextCount; // leave room on the array for the next remaining elements
        for (let i = start; i < end; i += 1) {
            // we have already used the element at (start - 1)
            result[result.length - count] = array[i];
            const nextStart = i + 1; // Always choose the next element from the ones following the last chosen element
            yield* _combinations(array, nextCount, nextStart, result);
        }
    };

    function* combinations(array, count) {
        yield* _combinations(array, count, 0, Array(count));
    }

    function* range(l) {
        for (let i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
            yield i;
        }
    }
    return {
        combinations,
        range,
    };
})();

const subArraysBy = (predicate, array) => {
    const result = [];
    for (const [beg, end] of combinations([...range(array.length+1)], 2)) {
        const subArray = array.slice(beg, end);
        if (predicate(subArray)) {
            result.push(subArray);
        }
    }
    return result;
};

const sum = array => array.reduce((sum, e) => sum + e);

console.log(
    subArraysBy(
        a => sum(a) === 5,
        [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 8, -3],
    ),
);
```

References:

- MDN: [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- MDN: [function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) -- not required for your solution
- Lodash: [_.range](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#range) -- implemented this in my code rather than use the lodash one.  They work similarly.
- Python Docs: [combinations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) - My combinations implementation is inspired by python itertools.